# Number of points of an affine variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and dependence on the degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $d$, $m$ and $k$ be positive integers. Consider the polynomials $f_1,\cdots,f_m\in \mathbb{F}_p[X_1,\cdots,X_d]$, each of degree at most $k$. The common zeros of these $m$ polynomials define an affine subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}^d$.

The [Lang-Weil bound](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/the-lang-weil-bound/) gives a lower bound on the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points of $V$ (also an upper bound, but I only need the lower bound).

It is of the form $|V(\mathbb{F}_p)|\geq(c(V)-Q\cdot p^{-1/2})\cdot p^{\dim(V)}$, for $Q=Q(d,m,k)$, and where $c(V)$ is the number of geometrically irreducible components of $V$ of dimension $\dim(V)$ which are definable over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Treat $d$ and $m$ as constants. How does $Q$ depend on $k$? Can it be taken to be a polynomial in $k$?